# free-jqgrid treegrid leaf node click event

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

I am trying to capture the click event of a treegrid leaf node in order to trigger a refresh of another instance of a free-jqGrid gridview.  I am using free-jqGrid 4.13.2.  I have looked at the source code for the treegrid, but I don't see a function that fires when the leaf node is clicked.

I have tried using a custom formatter in the gridview, replacing the cellvalue with a div with an onclick event that will refresh the gridview.  It works the first time (it refreshes the gridview), but after that, it does not and the only thing I see is the icons in the gridview toolbar are duplicating with each click of the treegrid leaf node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tree jqGrid have many callbacks for TreeGrid nodes, but the leaf will be interpreted as a simple row with data. Thus you have to use the `beforeSelectRow`, `onCellSelect` or `onSelectRow` to detect the required click. The callback have `rowid` as the first parameter and you can use `getLocalRow` to get the data of the row based on the `rowid`. The corresponding code will be very simple:

```js
beforeSelectRow: function (rowid, e) {
    var item = $(this).jqGrid("getLocalRow", rowid);

    if (item != null && item.isLeaf) {
        alert("The row with leaf \"" + item.name + "\" is clicked");
    }
    return true;   // allow row selection
}
```

[The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/LocalAdjacencyTree-fa4-leafClick.htm) demonstrates the code. You can use `e.target` to get more exact information about clicked cell. For example `$(e.target).closest("tr.jqgrow>td")` will get you the jQuery wrapper to the DOM element of clicked `<td>` cell.

Comment: Thanks Oleg!  I guess I didn't think about the connection between Tree and Grid jqGrid.  It makes sense now and I will remember that in the future.

Comment: Can we define ngclick event in the grid cell so that if we are using multiple grids it should behave different for each grid for ex instead of alert if we want another property we can just externalise it